# Simple program to sort numbers in C

Tags: c, sorting, numbers

What exactly is wrong with this program that I wrote? I saw some bubble sort stuff with two for loops but I don't see why this one doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main(){

    int a[6];
    int i;
    int temp;
    int n;

    printf("Enter numbers.\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        n = i + 1;

        if (a[i] < a[n])
        {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[n];
            a[n] = temp;
        }
    }

    printf("After sorting: \n");

    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d  ", a[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: What did you find out when you debugged your code?

Comment: The bubble sorts you saw probably had two nested loops for a reason. By the way, you access `a[6]` when `i` is 5.

Answer (score 1):

Your bubble sort algorithm is wrong. You're doing just one cycle on your array. At the end of the first cycle, the array is not sorted.

If your array is :  8 54 1 15 12 6

```
i = 0 ---> 8 54 1 15 12 6
i = 1 ---> 8 1 54 15 12 6
i = 2 ---> 8 1 15 54 12 6
i = 3 ---> 8 1 15 12 54 6
i = 4 ---> 8 1 15 12 6 54
i = 5 ---> a[6] points out of the array
```

After one cycle you'll have: 8 1 15 12 6 54

which is not sorted, you have to do more cycle (two nested for):

```
int i,k;
int temp;

for(i = 0; i<n-1; i++) {
    for(k = 0; k<n-1-i; k++) {
        if(v[k] > v[k+1]) {
            temp = v[k];
            v[k] = v[k+1];
            v[k+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

As M Oehm stated in the question comment, when `i` is 5, you access through `n` to a memory not in your array, which leads to potential segfaults.

Comment: I'm not trying to use bubblesort. I'm trying to sort using the simplest algorithm. I want to know why exactly the code I wrote doesn't sort it.

Comment: Ok, but you're swapping two near elements, which is bubble sort. Look at the first part of my answer, it should explain why you can't sort with just one cycle.